# Apple SignIn and Update Firebase email

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Apple sign in to login users to my app and then authenticate on firebase. Now sometimes users do not share their email in which case Apple provides a fictious email. After sign in am storing the emails in a database by verifying them first with firebase. I update the fictious email with a real one first on firebase and then send verification email. After updating the primary email on firebase, can the user loggin again with Apple given that Apple will still provide the old fictious email.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
await firebaseUser.updateEmail(email);
await firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update the email of a user using "Sign in with Apple", the user will still be able to login as they normally do.

Notice that there are 2 emails on the account, one set at the provider level (eg. `user.providerData[0].email`) and one at the top level (`user.email`).

On account creation (first sign up with Apple), both emails will be set to the one provisioned by Apple. After the `updateEmail` operation, the top level one (`user.email`) will be updated but the other one (`user.providerData[0].email`) will remain the same.